# VBA Search on different Worksheet failing

Tags: excel, vba, search, worksheet

Sorry for what is probably a stupid question. I am trying to use VBA search in Excel on a different sheet, I was getting somewhere, then it just stopped working.

```
Public Sub SearchForStudent()

    'Declare vars
    Dim StudentId As String
    Dim rgFound As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("AllStudents")
    Dim rngLook As Range: Set rngLook = ws.Range("P:P")
    Dim FoundRow As Integer
    
    'Set student ID from dropdown in B2
    StudentId = Range("B2").Value
    
    'Look up the cell that it is in
    Set rgFound = rngLook.Find(StudentId)
    
    'Find the row of the result
    FoundRow = rgFound.Row
    
    MsgBox FoundRow

End Sub
```

FoundRow doesn't get set, even though I know the data is there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

1. Avoid using `Integer` when working with rows. Excel 2007+ has `1048576` rows. So we should always declare the variable which will hold the row value as `Long` instead of `Integer`. If you try storing say, `1048576` to `Integer Variable` then you will get an **Overflow** error.
2. `.Find` remembers it's last setting. See the complete syntax at [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). So it is better to fully specify the parameters.
3. When using `.Find`, always check if `.Find` returned something to avoid breaking the code.

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Public Sub SearchForStudent()
    'Declare vars
    Dim StudentId As String
    Dim rgFound As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("AllStudents")
    Dim rngLook As Range: Set rngLook = ws.Range("P:P")
    Dim FoundRow As Long
    
    'Set student ID from dropdown in B2
    '~~> Ensure the below range is fully qualified
    StudentId = Range("B2").Value
    
    'Look up the cell that it is in
    '~~> Adjust the parameters as you want them
    Set rgFound = rngLook.Find(What:=StudentId, _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False)
        
    '~~> Check if the Find returned anything
    If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then
        FoundRow = rgFound.Row
        MsgBox FoundRow
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout, This fixes the issue of there being an error, but does not remove the fact that it doesn't find it. B2 uses Data Validation to pull the cell values from the P column on the AllStudents sheet. The only thing I can think is that maybe because this is a calculated field, it is finding the Formula instead of the actual value. On changing the value of this to "BOB" and placing a "BOB" in the list of IDs, it certainly seems this way. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sorry, hit return, see edit.

Comment: xlValues fixed it. I think you resolved my issue. Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Glad it worked out